# How to make a auto generated pdf purchasable in woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm making an ecommerce site using WordPress and WooCommerce. I want to sell auto generated PDF files, that is generated when the customer fills out a form.

After the customer fills out the form, I want them to pay and then download it.

I have already made the forms and the PDF is generated and saved on my server.

What i need is a way for WooCommerce to automatically find the pdf and make it a product which is downloadable after.

Any help is much appreciated!

I have tried to use WooCommerce rest api and then add an Ajax request to add the product to the cart.

The code I used is this snippet:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/wc/v3/cart/add',
  method: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa( 'consumer_key:consumer_secret' ) );
  },
  data: {
    product_id: '123', // I need to replace this with a unique name for the pdf.
    quantity: 1
  },
});
```

I can't get it to work, and i don't know why.. Please help me